# AudioSource.VOICE_CALL samsung galaxy

Tags: android

I have two Samsung Galaxy S2, same provider (H3G Italy), same firmware (2.3.5) bought together in same shop.

I develop an app for call recording, using mediarecorder and using as audiosource VOICE_CALL, this work well on one device and not on second.

During the debug there is no errors in Log, just the app stuck.

The Mediarecorder.start is called on PhoneStateListener status change, I tried with all audio format available in mediarecorder but no success.

If in mediarecorder.setaudiosource I add also VOICE_UPLINK then the app do not freeze anymore, but the audio quality is too low.

How is possible that two same mobile, same code and same development PC, one work fantastic and an other not?

Comment: Also trying with AudioRecorder, this work well on both devices, but the problem of AudioRecorder is te size of the wav file.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the original .wav file by using AudioRecorder.
And then you need to encode it into other format of audio files you want.
For example [this project](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid) provides a method to use lame libs to encode the .wav file to MP3.
By setting up the output sampling rate bit you can get the mp3 file with the size you want.